# Can SVN create tag on revision X but exclude some previous revisions?

Tags: svn, starteam

Let's say for example that I'd like to mark revision 30 of my project as Version1.5
and revision 40 as Version1.6 
I also don't want revision 18 to be part of the this Version1.5, only as part of Version1.6 - is there any way to exclude revision from a specifc tag?

In Starteam for example this concept is possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I can accept the other answer to this question. 
My investigation lead me to believe that creating selective tag in SVN that doesn't include all the reviosions that were made is not a build in behvaior of SVN unlike Starteam for example.
That because the revision in SVN are project bases and not on each file seperately.

Answer (score 1):

SVN doesn't like you to commit to tags by convention, so I would do this:
- create a branch called Version 1.5 from r30
- create a branch called Version 1.6 from r40
- switch to branch Version 1.5, revert revision 18 and tag it as Version 1.5
- tag branch Version 1.6 as tag Version 1.6